# ¿Verificar números/cantidades repetidas de una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, random

Estoy buscando la manera de agregar números repetidos de una lista que se genero con ***random*** utilizando ***colecctions***.

Mi idea fue utilizar ***from collections import Counter***

```
# Buscar la manera de que guarde los numeros mas repetidos, solo tengo 3 giradas.
from collections import Counter
import random

tirada = []
for i in range(5):
    tirada.append(random.randint(1, 6))

repetidos = Counter(tirada)
lista_repetidos = []

print(tirada) >>> [5, 4, 2, 4, 4]

print(repetidos) >>> Counter({4: 3, 5: 1, 2: 1})

print(repetidos.most_common(1)) >>> [(4, 3)]
```

En este caso el numero **4** se repitió **3** veces y mi idea es agregarlo a una lista para que quede de esta manera pero no encuentro la manera, ya que lo único que termino haciendo es sumar todo y me queda solo un numero:

```
lista_repetidos = [4, 4, 4]
```

Espero que se haya entendido, gracias de ante-mano.

Comment: haz `lista_repetidos= [[k]*v for k,v in repetidos.items()]`

Answer (score 0):

otra manera para poder almacenar sólo los repetidos en una lista podría ser siguiendo su código algo así:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 


from collections import Counter
import random
tirada = []
for i in range(5):  
  tirada.append(random.randint(1, 6))

repetidos = Counter(tirada)
lista_repetidos = []

print('valores de la tirada: \n',tirada)

print('----------\nrepeticiones de cada tirada: \n',repetidos)

for i in repetidos:
  if repetidos.get(i)>1:       
    lista_repetidos.append(i)

print('----------\nlista de numeros repetidos: \n',lista_repetidos)
```

Al final simplemente recorro el diccionario donde se muestran las repeticiones de cada tirada y los valores mayores de 1 los almaceno en la lista de repeticiones.
Espero sea útil, un salu2